# How do you securely create admin users for a web application?

Tags: node.js, express, security, web-applications, admin

I'm in the early stages of developing a web application right now, and I have a User model that includes an `isAdmin` field with a default of `false`. I am preventing users from setting this during registration or profile editing by selecting which fields to update in the get/put routes. See example:

```
exports.editUser = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay } = req.body;
    const dob = formatDob(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay);

    const user = await db.User.findById(req.params.id); 
    const updates = pick(req.body, [ 'fullName', 'email', 'password', 'gender', 'address', 'avatar_url' ]);
    merge(user, updates, {dob});
    let updatedUser = await user.save();
    return res.status('200').json(updatedUser); 
  }
```

Right now I am considering the best way of creating or modifying admin users. If I create a separate set of Admin routes for creating/modifying/etc, wherein we can set `isAdmin` to `true`, then anyone who can guess the route would be able to create an admin user. How can this be done securely?

Similarly, there are certain things I want Admins to be able to do that users cannot. Would I protect those routes with a separate middleware that verifies they are an admin?

Comment: I think protect `/admin/*` routes with a middleware is a good idea.

Comment: So you would recommend keeping admins separate from the User model? Or have a separate create route that creates a user with isAdmin: true that is protected by middleware? (Hypothetically I could also add a discriminator for Admins in Mongoose)

Comment: I suggest protect the route with middleware, but not separate them in the DB model level.